# Converting iPhone App to Universal

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am attempting to convert my iPhone app to a universal app so I have added a new Storyboard for the iPad. Is it better to modify the existing VCs with device checks and code to handle the iPad or should I duplicate these ViewControllers and modify them for iPad compatibility?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry for the lack of information. I wasn't sure what I kind of additional information I needd to give. I am using the newest version of 6.1.

The views are essentially the same except that it's going to be optimized for the screen space. Here is the structure:

1. Login Controller (Almost exactly the same except for a minor detail)
2. Home View Controller 
   In the iPhone it was just a TableView that pushes a a detail views (3 VCs from paging)
   In the iPad I want to use a split view that uses the TableView and Detail View all on one screen.

Thanks

Comment: as you are giving us no information about the requirements, there is no waxy to give you a valid answer.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? Also how do the UIs differ between devices? Do you have all the same views just different sizes and positions or do you use entirely new view types?

Comment: and again: what does «optimized for the screen space» mean? just stretching or rearranging…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you. Personally, I like to use the same view controllers for the same views even if they relate differently to one another. For example, the TidBITS News app has navigation controller, master view (table of story titles), and detail view (individual story) on iPhone, but split view controller containing both master view and detail view on iPad. There are two storyboards, but just one MasterViewController class file and one DetailViewController class file. Now, of course, those files contain a bit of conditional code (do one thing if we are running on iPhone and a different thing if we are running on iPad). I hate that, but what can you do?

If you just make a new Universal project starting with Master-Detail template I think you'll see that that's exactly how it works.

Comment: My problem is my DetailView on the iPhone consists of 3 VCs. I am guessing I can make reuse some VCs and make new ones on others.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a TableView on iPhone and a SplitViewController on iPad you will need different ViewController classes. For the Login Controller you could reuse your view controller for both devices. Since you have the ability to reference your view controller on a per view basis, you can pick and choose where it makes sense to reuse view controllers for both device families. You may want to consider using a .XIB for the login view controller as you may be able to have a single view definition if you use AutoLayout.